# Is there any way I can use to change the download behaviors on google chrome pdf viewer

Tags: google-chrome, pdf-viewer

I want to know that is there any way i can use to change the behaviour of download button on
google chrome built-in pdf viewer plugin.

I want to check some conditions to make sure the user can download the pdf file when user click 'download' button on pdf viewer.

So I need to execute some js code before the pdf viewer start to download/stop to download the pdf file.

I could not find any document about the API for google chrome pdf viewer...

If any way I can do it? thanks for your help!!!